# Знак \ в echo "\$arr[$key] = $value </br> ";

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
$arr= array( 2, 5, 9, 15, 0, 4);
foreach ($arr as  $key=>$value){
    if ($value < 10 && $value>3)
        echo "\$arr[$key] = $value </br> ";
}
```

Вывод:

```
$arr[1] = 5
$arr[2] = 9
$arr[5] = 4;
```

Если же в строке `echo "\$arr[$key] = $value </br> "` убираем `\` вывод будет следующий:

```
5 = 5
9 = 9
4 = 4
```

Никак не могу понять почему не

```
1 = 5 
2 = 9 
5 = 4
```

Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: когда вы ставите слэш, выводится строка, потому что он экранирует знак доллара, иначе php делает подстановку переменной в строке. Если хотите, чтобы подстановки не было, то или так как в вопросе, или в одинарных кавычках

Comment: Потому, что у Вас получается без слеша обращение `$arr[$key]`, что эквивалентно `$value`. А со слешем вывод только ключа `$key`, поскольку сам массив экранирован(`\$` воспринимается как простой символ, а не обращение к переменной) и не происходит поиска по нему. Для нужной Вам строки используется `echo "$key = $value </br> "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом случае:

```
echo "\$arr[$key] = $value </br> ";
```

вы экранируете первый символ $, таким образом в строке получается только две переменные `$key` и `$value`, при этом `$arr` распознаётся как строка. Отсюда такой вывод.

Во втором случае:

```
echo "$arr[$key] = $value </br> ";
```

`$arr[$key]` воспринимается как переменная, значение которой и будет равно `$value`. Отсюда одинаковые значения.

Следующий код выведет необходимый результат:

```
echo "$key = $value </br> ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить такой результат как хотите Вы, выводите данные следующим образом:

```
echo $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы используете выражение внутри строки, то обрамляйте его круглыми скобками:
При этом допустимо обрамлять и просто переменную.

`echo "$key = ${arr[$key]}";`
Разумеется в вашем случае справа допустимо использовать значение `$value`. Я лишь привёл синтаксис.